# Youtube Login Api OAuth 2.0 flutter

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I've been trying for a bit to implement login of youtube channels on my app. but all I could do was google accounts with `google_sign_in 4.5.1`

has any of you implemented this feature and can give me an hint? youtube docs are terrible

edit:
here's the code

```
class AuthService {
String oAuthClientId = '**hidden**'; // not used?

  static List<String> scopes = [
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', // Youtube scope
  ];

     final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: scopes,
  );



Future<FirebaseUser> login() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
  accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
  idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
);

final token = googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken;

final AuthResult authResult = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
assert(!user.isAnonymous);
assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

final FirebaseUser currentUser = await auth.currentUser();
assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

var client = new http.Client();

return currentUser;


 }

  void signOut() {
    auth.signOut();
    googleSignIn.disconnect();
  }

  Future<FirebaseUser> getUser() async{
    final FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
    return user;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-implementing-google-sign-in-71888bca24ed

Answer (score 1):

To display your youtube channels, you'll need to add the youtube scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube` to your google login.

Prior to this, you must've setup enabled the Youtube api from your [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/enabled). Read the [Youtube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) for more information

Example login code:

```
login() async {
    GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: [
        'email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', // Youtube scope
      ],
    );
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
    await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );

    // You'll need this token to call the Youtube API. It expires every 30 minutes.
    final token = googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken; 
    
    final AuthResult authResult = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
  }
```

Comment: I see a firebase user there, would need firebase in it? okok

will try this out and let you know! thanks

Comment: Firebase isn't necessary but if you want to manage your users through `Firebase Authentication` you should use it

Comment: so i tried it out but the popup only shows me my emails and not channels, and when i press one I get get an error
"E/flutter (11805): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)"
I assumed I had a problem with firebase so I went to it to try and generate a google.services json but i get another error there Oauth client already exists in a different project for package name ... and certificate hash ... prob cause i tried to use OAuth 2.0 and failed...

Comment: The popup wont show you your channels. the popup is for login, after login you'll get a token(it's in the code). You'll use the token to make request to Youtube API. This error you're getting has to do with your firebase setup. look into that

Comment: well what if an user has multiple channels under an email and wants to pick one of those?

Comment: The API will handle that. READ  here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list.

You really should go through the youtube API

Comment: i tried that before, it won't make the connection between email and channel. i have to give the channel ID to fetch that

Comment: in my case pop up stuck on loading after clicking on gmail account , any suggestions?